# Why does DLIB compute the square root of LBP uniform descriptor?

Tags: c++, image-processing, feature-extraction, dlib, lbph-algorithm

I'm using dlib library to extract LBP uniform from a given image. 
I'm using next function (http://dlib.net/dlib/image_transforms/lbp_abstract.h.html#extract_uniform_lbp_descriptors) but I don't understand exactly what's the function of the third parameter (`cell_size`). In the documentacion says the next:

> We will have taken the square root of all the histogram elements. That is,  `#feats[i]` is the square root of the number of LBPs that appeared in its corresponding window.

I don't know when says '`#feats[i]` is the square root of the number of LBPs'. What's refering? 
If anyone can help me I'd grateful...
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See description of LBP at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_binary_patterns.

Actually you devide image into square cells and build 59-bin histogram for every cell, comparing each point in a cell with its neighbours. The third parameter (cell_size) defines size of these cells.
Then histoghams from all cells are concatinated into a long 59*(number of cells) resulting vector  std::vector& feats.

Answer (score 1):

It is widely accepted that using a square root (Hellinger) kernel instead of the standard Euclidean distance to measure the similarity between feature distributions improves classification accuracy.

For two LBP histograms

[image: x]

and

[image: y]

their [Hellinger distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance) is defined as:

[image: H(x,y)]

The Hellinger kernel classifier can be implemented in a straightforward way by using the square root of the LBP histograms as feature vectors, and the Euclidean distance as dissimiliarity measure. This is why the number of LBPs is square rooted in the reference code.